# Cannot transcode invalid UTF-8 JSON text to UTF-16 string

Tags: f#, f#-data

Given the function:

```
   let postData url (payload:JObject) =
        Http.RequestString
            (url,
            headers = [HttpRequestHeaders.ContentType HttpContentTypes.Json],
            body = HttpRequestBody.TextRequest (payload |> string))
```

I am unable to send the data to the backend as it fails with the error:

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.


 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot transcode invalid UTF-8 JSON text to UTF-16 string.
 ---> System.Text.DecoderFallbackException: Unable to translate bytes [E9] at index 629 from specified code page to Unicode.
   at System.Text.DecoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Throw(Byte[] bytesUnknown, Int32 index)
   at System.Text.DecoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Fallback(Byte[] bytesUnknown, Int32 index)
   at System.Text.Encoding.GetCharCountWithFallback(ReadOnlySpan`1 bytes, Int32 originalBytesLength, DecoderNLS decoder)
   at System.Text.Encoding.GetCharCountWithFallback(Byte* pBytesOriginal, Int32 originalByteCount, Int32 bytesConsumedSoFar)
   at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetCharCount(Byte* bytes, Int32 count)
   at System.String.CreateStringFromEncoding(Byte* bytes, Int32 byteLength, Encoding encoding)
   at System.Text.Encoding.GetString(ReadOnlySpan`1 bytes)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonReaderHelper.TranscodeHelper(ReadOnlySpan`1 utf8Unescaped)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Text.Json.JsonReaderHelper.TranscodeHelper(ReadOnlySpan`1 utf8Unescaped)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.GetRawValueAsString(Int32 index)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonElement.ToString()
   at lambda_method(Closure , CreateContainerCommand , Container , ResolutionContext )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at lambda_method(Closure , CreateContainerCommand , Container , ResolutionContext )
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object , ResolutionContext )
```

**BUT** the same request with the same *body* works just fine from Postman. What am I missing?

btw. printfn of `payload |> string` also prints the object just fine

Comment: Just troubleshooting ideas, not answers... have you tried logging the requests with something like Fiddler to confirm the request you're submitting is the same as your Postman request? What happens if you replace `payload |> string` with `sprintf "%s" payload |> string`. What happens if you use a normal HttpClient (it appears you are using FSharp.Data/WebClient?)? I get on better with HttpClient generally, even though FSharp.Data provides a nice API for HTTP.

Comment: Turns out, it works just fine with HttpClient :S Now it's even more confusing. thanks though @drkmtr for the suggestions.

Comment: Mmm... my only guess would be that you'd need to access the WebClient instance, and do some sort of character encoding config e.g. `wc.Encoding <- Encoding.UTF16` where `wc` is your WebClient. I had to do this for a different reason (ignoring auto-redirects in http responses) and decided I may as well switch to HttpClient if I'm going to have to "work around" the `FSharp.Data` API.